# SQL IF ELSE Statement

Tags: c#, winforms, sql-server-2008-r2

I'm creating an Insert Query in `C# WinForms`, to `INSERT` members into a database table (Members).
 I'm using this code:

```
IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM Members WHERE PersonalId = @PersonalId)
BEGIN
INSERT INTO Members (PersonalId, FirstName, LastName, City, PhoneNumber)
VALUES (@PersonalId, @FirstName, @LastName, @City, @PhoneNumber)
END
```

(`@PersonalId,` should have the value that the user types in the `textbox`?)

This pop up :

[image]

Any help ?

Comment: Can you add your c# code as well?

Comment: pass the parameter value  for ` @PersonalId`

Answer (score 3):

That suggests you are missing a parameter. You should have something like:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("PersonalId", personalId);
```

where (importantly) `personalId` ***is not `null`*** (it can be `DBNull.Value`, though).

> (@PersonalId, should have the value that the user types in the textbox?)

It probably should, but it sounds like you haven't added it correctly.

Comment: Or potentially it could be one of the `gotcha`'s that I suffer from all the time - `cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;`. Not specifying that usually results in paremeter related exceptions

Comment: It will be added but usually results in an exception, I always add parameters as specificed but unless I specify the command type I get an exception. Was just a note from personal experience, I +1'd anyway :)

Comment: @Luke I do "quite a bit" of DAL stuff (including writing a micro-ORM), and I can't say as I've noticed that. I'd be interested in more detail, but I *suspect* it is not directly related to this scenario.

Comment: @MarcGravell no, not setting CommandType.StoredProcedure means the parameter is ignored. I had exactly the same problem just yesterday, turned out to be a school boy CommandType error.

Comment: @CarlSixsmith parameters are most certainly **not** ignored when calling text commands, at least not by most ADO.NET providers; I use fully-parameterised text commands **all the time**. The only time parameters are ignored is when their `.Value` is `null` (as opposed to `DBNull.Value` or any other non-null value). What ADO.NET provider are you using? i.e. what is the connection type? (the tag here is sql-server-*, so I'm assuming the OP is using `SqlConnection`, which **definitely** doesn't ignore parameters on text commands)

Comment: That's the difference, I was trying to put the procedure name as the command text.

I get an exception because the parameter is not null even though the parameter has been added to the SQLCommand.

Comment: @Carl ah, gotcha; in that scenario the parameters *were sent* - just that your code didn't use them. It is perhaps unfortunate that `EXEC` can be implicit - the problem would be much more obvious if it refused to run `SomeProc` (by itself) as command-text, but was happy to run `EXEC SomeProc` - which would then normally prompt you that you've made a mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Why would you do that?? Instead of this thing simply define the column as `Unique` or maybe even better as a `Primary key` (if your table doesn't already have a PK).
After you've done it, your SQL server will take care of it, because if the column is marked as unique or PK, it won't allow other items to have the same value in the column.

There's really no need to put this logic into every SQL insert...

Your error says one thing - you haven't defined the parameter @PersonalId, but I think it's a bad way to take..

Comment: How is that any different from having a guard clause in a method rather than letting null exceptions get thrown?

Comment: @CarlSixsmith, what do you mean by "how"? If the column has to have an unique value, it should be marked as such in advance. Putting additional logic inside queries is counterproductive. It won't affect only inserts, but updates as well. He'll have to check for uniqueness every single time something changes in the table. What if some other programmer will come at some later point and won't know that he needs to check for this? He looks at the table and doesn't see any constraints. Why to move this logic from table definition to separate queries? I don't see a single reason why to do this.

Comment: Because catching exceptions is highly inefficient in a high volume systems.

No reason not to do both.

Comment: @CarlSixsmith exceptions are not *usually* any kind of problem, even in high volume systems. Besides: trying to insert something that already exists *is a problem* - it suggests something needs to abort, now.

Comment: @CarlSixsmith, what about duplication of code/logic? Furthermore, you have to somehow notify the user that the query wasn't successful. If you check for this in the insert query itself, insert won't happen and the user won't ever know unless you make another query for the database and check for new record... THAT is efficient? Sorry, but I really can't see your point...

Comment: It's quite common to have scenarios where you want to add something if it's missing, otherwise ignore the request. 

Do this at the lowest level is far more efficient than catching exceptions.

Catching exceptions to handle code flow is extremely inefficient.